# segfault when referencing virtual function within pointer class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

This program is a game, in which a dynamic 2d array board is full of room classes. Each room class has a private pointer event class, which is going to inherit one of four different child classes. My goal is to have virtual functions the event class within each child class, so that I may call a pure virtual function in event which would return a string from the inherited child class. I'm getting a seg fault error though. Here is my simplified code:

```
//in game class
    board[1][1].set_bat();  
    board[1][1].get_message();

//room.h
    class room {
        private:
        event *ev;  //here, each room class is given an event class pointer
    public:
        void set_bat();
        void get_message();

    };

//in room.cpp
    void room::set_bat(){  //here, the event pointer is set to one of its child classes.
        bats x;
        ev = &x;
        //ev->message(); if the message func is called here, it return "bats" correctly, 
    }
    void room::get_message(){ //calling this, is where the error occurs
        ev->message();
    }

//in event.h
    class event {
        public:
            virtual void message() = 0;
    };

//in bats.h
    class bats: public event{
    public:   
        void message();
    };

 //in bats.cpp
    void bats::message(){
        cout<<"bats"<<endl;
    }
```

The end goal would be for whenever I call get_message in the game class, it would return the string from the virtual function, even if the event within a room was for something different such as a pit, where it would return the string "pit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
void room::set_bat(){  //here, the event pointer is set to one of its child classes.
    bats x;
    ev = &x;
    //ev->message(); if the message func is called here, it return "bats" correctly, 
}
```

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. This variable goes out of scope when the function returns, and hence `ev` now points to garbage.
You should use `new` for allocating pointers:

```
void room::set_bat(){
    ev = new bats();
}
```

This also means you should define a destructor for your `room` class that calls `delete ev`:

```
class room {
    private:
    event *ev;  //here, each room class is given an event class pointer
public:
    void set_bat();
    void get_message();
    ~room() { delete ev; } // ADDED
};
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, and I can see how what I was doing was wrong.